# php+python на web сервере. Динамический вывод информации на сайт

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование, парсер, веб-интерфейс

на вебсервере находится скрипт на питоне, который парсит данные. Запускает его пользователь через браузер с помощью php. Скрипт работает около часа и при этом периодически выводит с помощью print('Обработано 10% данных'), print('Обработано 20% данных') разную информацию о своих успехах. Когда работа скрипта заканчивается, вся эта информация разом отображается в браузере. Но при таком процессе, пользователь не видет в течение всей работы скрипта его прогресс.

Пожалуйста подскажите какими способами можно отображать информацию о работе скрипта более динамично?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title>MarketCost</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Обработка данных..</p>

<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/home/l/lbtdmega/.local/bin/python3.8 /home/l/lbtdmega/ltd/costmarket.ps');
$output = shell_exec($command);
var_dump($output);
echo $output;
echo '--!'
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619996/how-to-run-ruby-python-scripts-from-inside-php-passing-and-receiving-parameters

Comment: Для получения прогресса надо как-то его отсылать посетителю сайта. Это делается либо по запросу с его браузера, либо когда сервер это отправляет туда через механизм типа WebSockets. В первом случае вам надо сохранять прогресс чтобы он был доступен для чтения, во втором - передавать вывод консольной строки в websocket поток.